Unattended.xml Windows 10 to Windows 11 InplaceUpgrade
I´m currently trying to do an inplace upgrade of Windows 10 to 11.
I extracted the install.wim from the Win11 iso and mounted it with dism.
I placed the Unattend.xml in Windows\system32\sysprep\ and replaced the install.wim in the iso with anyburn.
If I now run the inplace upgrade with setup.exe or sources\setupprep.exe it does not use that xml.
Also running from cmd with /Unattend does not work.
Is there any way to achieve this?

See https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/unattended-windows-11-installation.html for a guide.

I have a unattended file, also works for clean installs. But getting it to run in inplace upgrades does not.
